# scene looks good when rendered in 3D view but when i render it. it doesn't look right

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: after i selected the objects i didn't want to render][image: when i render it in the 3d view]
[![when i render it in the uv editor it looks like this][3]][3]
when i render my scene in the 3d view (the midle image) it looks good but when i render it in the uv editor(stack exchange wouldn't let more then one link) it looks wierd
then i went in to the outliner and made sure all the objects that i didn't want to render were not being rendered (the top image)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3D window renders, but Image Render doesn't?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18962/3d-window-renders-but-image-render-doesnt)

Comment: Check if all objects in the outliner will be rendered and the number of samples in the Render section

Comment: ya shortly after i made this thread i check that and i didn't help

Comment: i fix it i just selected everything and moved it to a new layer thx tho